# How to write JPA query where parameter is a set?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Assuming the following class, how do you find a `Person` with a particular email address?

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id = 0;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<String> email = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

Is it as simple as doing just this, or is there a proper way?

```
select p from Person p where p.email=:email
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not that easy. JPQL provides the `IN` operator for this:

```
select p from Person p, IN(p.email) m where m = :email
```

The 'old' way (read SQL-like) would be:

```
select p from Person p join p.email m where m = :email
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL would look something like this:

```
WHERE email IN ('foo@yahoo.com', 'bar@gmail.com')
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of an easy way to do this.  If you were doing this with raw SQL, you'd have to do it in two steps: create a bind parameter `?` for each value in the set, then iterate through the set and bind each value to its bind parameter.

I'm not aware of a way to do it cleanly in JPA, but that's what you should be looking for.