# Quering depending on children id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write JPA query where parameter is a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492018/how-to-write-jpa-query-where-parameter-is-a-set)

I have 2 entities

```
@Entity
public class Container {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Child> data = newHashSet();
}
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
}
```

Now I want select all containers that contains specified child.
I wrote jpa query `select c from Container c where :child in c.data` that produce sql

```
select 
    container0_.id as id4_ 
from 
    Container container0_ 
    cross join Container_Child data1_, Child child2_ 
where 
    container0_.id=data1_.Container_id 
and data1_.data_id=child2_.id 
and (? in (.)) 
limit ? [42001-168]
```

and fails with `JdbcSQLException`. How can I fix it?

Comment: oops! Ignore my comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492018/how-to-write-jpa-query-where-parameter-is-a-set - isn't it the same as your problem?

Comment: Try: SELECT con FROM Container con JOIN con.data ch WHERE ch = :child

Comment: @mykhaylo thanks it's work. Would you please post it as answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: @miller.bartek It's not quite the same since here childs are Entities, not primitives.

Comment: But the answer provided is exactly the same: 
select p from Person p join p.email m where m = :email

Comment: @miller.bartek Ok. You are right. What I should do with this topic? I voted to close it.

Comment: Leave it as it is. Please google more the next time, because it took me less than 30 seconds to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `SELECT con FROM Container con JOIN con.data ch WHERE ch = :child`