# How to write JPA query If the Entity is Having HashSet with some Customized Object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, hashset

Assuming the following class, how to retrieve particular Department Id record from the Employee table?

```
public class Employee{

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,   CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Department> departmentSet = new HashSet<Department>();
```

}

I have tried like below from the [How to write JPA query where parameter is a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492018/how-to-write-jpa-query-where-parameter-is-a-set) but not getting the expected result.

```
select e from Employee e f WHERE :department in departmentSet(e.departmentSet)
```

Could someone please assist on how to use customized sets.

Comment: *how to the particular Department*: could you please clarify what you want to achieve? Have you read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql?

Comment: sorry, it is actually   "how to retrieve particular Department Id from the Employee table"  I have edited the post.

Comment: You want all departmentIds from one Employee? One Employee can have many Departments

Comment: I have just taken that as a sample example but my requirement is Set with customized object and I need to retrieve the record based the customized object property. I have verified above link but still I don't have any clue.

Comment: That's still very unclear. You have employees. Employees belong to many departments. Now what is your input, and what do you want the query to find and return? Joins are very much explained, with examples, in the documentation. Your set has nothing "custom". It's a standard OneToMany association between entities.